# want to format text in XML having mixed content using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to convert below XML in the specified format. Can I do this using XSLT 2.0?

Basically, I want to put text in some elements and order the new text elements and existing child elements in a particular order, so my xml serializer can serialize the output xml to the appropriate class properties.

Input XML:

```
<properties>
My Parent level text 1
<child1>  
text1 of first child <b> in bold</b>  
<childval>36-37</childval> 
text2 of child <i> in italic </i> 
</child1>
My Parent level text2 in <i>italic</i> also in <b>bold </b>
</properties>
```

Expected output XML:

```
<properties>
  <parenttext order="1">My Parent level text 1</parenttext>
  <child1 order="2">  
    <childtext childorder="1" > text1 of first child <b> in bold</b>     
    </childtext>
    <childval childorder="2">36-37</childval> 
    <childtext childorder="3" >text2 of child <i> in italic </i>  
    </childtext>
  </child1>
  <parenttext order="3">My Parent level text2 in <i>italic</i> also in <b>bold </b> 
  </parenttext>
</properties>
```

Comment: How much variety is there in the input structure? I.e. Are there always 2 "parent level texts" and 1 child with 2 text nodes in it?

Comment: Not really, Data is very dynamic. But what I desire is to get some trick to handle text and nodes in  the order they are.

Comment: Why is the second `parenttext` element of order="3"? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: order is 3 as it is at the third position in properties element.

Comment: This is redundant information that does not need to be stored. The position of child elements can easily be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

That is a nasty source structure you have there, if you can I'd start making changes in the source first ...

You could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="inlineElements" select="'b','i'"/>

<xsl:template match="properties">
    <properties>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::text() or self::node()[name()=$inlineElements]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()=true()">
                    <parenttext><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></parenttext>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </properties>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child1">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::text() or self::node()[name()=$inlineElements]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()=true()">
                    <childtext><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></childtext>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childval">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the Output you want minus your order attributes.

group-adjacent will examine all nodes and group everything that generates the same grouping-key together untill a node generates another grouping-key. So the text and inline nodes will generate true untill a child node comes which will generate false and so on...

---

Too add the order attribute afterwards in a second transformation you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:epub="hkda" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<!-- copy template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- match nodes which should have order nr -->
<xsl:template match="parrenttext | childtext | childval">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="orderno" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know if this can be made generic . As text I put is just a sample text and may vary. SO can there be any solution which works without <xsl:variable name="xml">. Because current xslt provided by you works only on this static data. Please correct me if required.

Comment: The <xsl:variable name="xml"> was just in there for demonstration purposes, I removed it from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But how about order attribute? Is there no way we can achieve it?

Comment: Not sure how this is possible, I would probably just make a second transformation and ad the order attribut with the position of the element, that's rather easy than

Comment: I edited my answer with a second stylesheet that will give you the order nr.

Comment: Given this is XSLT 2.0 you can merge the two transformations into one by giving one set of templates a different `mode`, then doing a two-phase transform (`<xsl:variable name="phase1"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:variable>` and then `<xsl:apply-templates mode="phase2" select="$phase1" />`)

Comment: Thanks for your responses till now . It is mostly working :).  I have a very varyign xml, so trying to see if it works for all my scenarios.I will get back to you in case i need any more help.

Comment: Hi, whenver i have attributes defined for elements (child1, chaildval), i loose them due to this transformation. Will appreciate your help to solve this.

Comment: for attributes, I have changed xsl as below:

Comment: CAn you please help em to remove the namespaces?

Comment: Please somebody respond