# How to add an XML element to an existing text in a XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, element, elementtree, xml-attribute

I have a problem with some values not being declared as XML elements in my XML files. But for further processing, I need them to be an element.
Example:

```
 <A>
    <B id="254">
        <C>Lore</C>
        <D>9</D> 
        12.34
    </B>
    <B id="255">
        <C>Ipsum</C>
        <D>125</D> 
        23.45
    </B>
    <E/>
    <F id="256">
        <G>Lore Ipsum
            <E>79</E> 
            34.56
        </G>
    </F>
</A>
```

In the end, the XML file should look similar to this:

```
<A>
    <B id="254">
        <C>Lore</C>
        <D>9</D> 
        <Z>12.34</Z> 
    </B>
    <B id="255">
        <C>Ipsum</C>
        <D>125</D> 
        <Z>23.45</Z>
    </B>
    <E/>
    <F id="256">
        <G>Lore Ipsum
            <E>79</E>
            <Y>34.56</Y> 
        </G>
    </F>
</A>
```

I looked in various python documentation but only found a way to add a new element with a value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326158/want-to-format-text-in-xml-having-mixed-content-using-xslt

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky thanks, for your answer. XSLT was used to solve this problem. I have already made some changes in Python to my XML file. Hence my question is there also a way to do these changes with Python

Comment: It is better to use native XML API like XSLT for such tasks.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75586178/12621346) question, now. First it was asked change this xml: <A id="0">
    <B>Lorem ipsum</B>
    <C>100</C>12.34
</A> to this Output: <A id="0">
    <B>Lorem ipsum</B>
    <C>100</C>
<D>12.34
</D></A>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the build in `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Start.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Show current XML
ET.dump(root)

# catch the tail value
for elem in root.iter():
    tail_text = elem.tail

# reset the tail value
for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag =="C":
        elem.tail = '\n'

# define new node
ET.SubElement(root, "D")

# assign the new nodes text
for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "D":
        elem.text = tail_text

# Show changed XML        
ET.dump(root)

# write the changed tree to a file
tree.write("new.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works for the XML File above. What if there is more than one nested element? I have updated the XML file in the problem description.

Comment: If you change your question after the answer you should open another question. The doing is the same you can loop over the whole tree. Please accept my answer to your first question. Thanks.